CLIO intregration in localhost
I am trying to integrate Clio in my localhost with below code:
Redirect url in the portal
$endpoint = "https://eu.app.clio.com/oauth/authorize";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', $endpoint, ['query' => [
         'response_type' => 'code', 
         'client_id' => '***',
         'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1/callback',
         'redirect_on_decline' => true,
 ]]);
$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();

I am trying to get code to generate token but callback url is not getting called to get generated code from clio.
Route::get('/callback', function () {
    Log::error(request()->query('code'));
    return response('OK', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
});

Getting nothing in my log.

Clio can't connect to your server on http://127.0.0.1/. It needs a publicly routable address, and 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address

But we can add it as a redirect url in development portal.

Just because you can doesn't mean it works. 127.0.0.1 is literally "localhost", which means "This computer". If I use 127.0.0.1, it's my computer. If you use it, it's your computer. If Clio uses it, it's their system.

So you are saying that we can't test it through localhost and I have to use only live URLs for that?

You'll need a routable test URL. You can test it on localhost, but you'll need to either use your external IP, if you can route external traffic to your computer, or use a service like ngrok to give you a tunnel for outside traffic
